# How to test JavaScript minification output

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

We recently upgraded to a newer build of a JavaScript minification library.

After a significant amount of quality assurance work by the testing team, it was discovered that the new version of our minifier had an issue that changed the intention and meaning behind a block of code.

(Life lesson: don't upgrade JS minifiers unless you are really convinced you need the new version.)

The minifier is used for client side JavaScript code with a heavy emphasis on DOM related activity, not nearly as much "business logic".

A simplified example of what was broken by the minifier upgrade:

```
function process(count)
{
     var value = ""; 
     value += count; //1. Two consecutive += statements
     value += count;
     count++;        //2. Some other statement
     return value;   //3. Return
}
```

Was minified incorrectly to the following:

```
function process(n){var t="";return t+n+n,n++,t}
```

While we could write some unit tests to catch some of the issues potentially, given that the JavaScript is heavy on DOM interactions (data input, etc.), it's very difficult to test thoroughly without user testing (non-automated). We'd pondered using a JS to AST library like Esprima, but given the nature of the changes that could be done to the minified code, it would produce far too many false positives.

We also considered trying to write representative tests, but that seems like a never-ending task (and likely to miss cases).

FYI: This is a very sophisticated web application with several hundred thousand lines of JavaScript code.

We're looking for a methodology for testing the minification process short of "just test everything again, thoroughly, and repeat." We'd like to apply a bit more rigor/science to the process.

Ideally, we could try multiple minifiers without fear of each breaking our code in new subtle ways if we had a better scientific method for testing.

Update:

One idea we had was to:

1. take minification with old version
2. beautify it
3. minify with new version,
4. beautify, and
5. visually diff.

It did seem like a good idea, however the differences were so common that the diff tool flagged nearly every line as being different.

Comment: Which minifier are you using?

Comment: I cannot state how much I related to this question. The example code was, hilarious, at best.

Comment: @Blender-Microsoft Ajax Minifier 4.74 in this case.

Comment: It may be possible to use a source map and compare the minified + source map to the original version.

Comment: @WillHawker - interesting. Assuming someone adjusted the minifier to produce a source map, wouldn't that rely on the source map being accurate? (I'm having a very hard time visualizing it -- even the example I gave that would be hard to parse and compare to an optimized/minified version, wouldn't it?)

Comment: @WiredPrairie, why would you ever trust Microsoft to do anything correctly with JavaScript? Have you ever used Internet Exploder? Use the YUI-Compressor or closure compiler.

Comment: @zzzzBov - changing wouldn't help or address the issue. Those aren't bug free either (and how could we prove it as I mentioned?)

Comment: @WiredPrairie, changing wouldn't address the question as you've posted, which is why I posted a comment, not an answer. My comment was more so that you'd use a tool that does a better job. Comparing source maps sounds like a much better choice

Comment: Changing minifiers *would* help the issue, though. There wasn't an issue until your current minifier started producing braindead code, right? Use a decent minifier and you'll be back to not having issues (sure there are caveats with closure, but they're mostly clearly documented and easy to avoid). Making sure the minifier actually works is the job of the people who work on the minifier, not your job.

Comment: It's a great question. Actually it convinced me that minification is a false economy considering the difficulty in debugging this obfuscated wizardry (or in your case, proving it). Most of the network-transfer benefit is delivered via browser caching and gzip compression. The cost and uncertainty around obfuscation minification isn't worth the penny-pinching benefit. Unless you already have a comprehensive suite of regression tests you can't make any changes of this nature with any confidence at all. So the cost of testing is going to exceed the benefit of minification over something so large.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski- While aggressive minification may not be as necessary anymore, I'd admittedly still like to remove comments before shipping. :)

Comment: Absolutely!  If minification is just removing the comments and maybe white-space, without obfuscation of the actual code, then that's going to be relatively safe.

Comment: what is the data type for `count`? Is it `string` or `number`?

Comment: @RayCheng -- why would it matter? The code produced is wrong. It was just a simplification of the actual problem. Not real code we use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a unit test framework, such as [QUnitjs](http://qunitjs.com/) ?  It would be quite a bit of work to write the unit tests, but in the end you would have a repeatable test procedure.

Comment: It's an interesting idea to consider for certain scenarios -- as our web app is very rich, unit testing JavaScript UI stuff has proven difficult. Do you have comments to add on what you've done to test JS/DOM heavy interactions using a unit testing framework?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to start using automated unit tests within your [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (continuous integration environment). QUnit has been thrown around, but really QUnit is a pretty weak testing system, and its assertions are bare-bones at the minimum (it doesn't even really use a good assertion-based syntax). It only marginally qualifies as [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and doesn't handle [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) very well either.

Personally, I'd recommend [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) with [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/GettingStarted) (it can use other unit test frameworks, or its own, and is incredibly fast...though it has some stability issues that I really wish they'd fix), and setup unit tests that can check minification processes by multiple comparisons.

Some comparisons would likely need to be:

- original code and its functionality behaves as expected
- compared to minified code (this is where BDD comes in, expect the same functional performance/results in minified code)
- I'd even go a step further (depending on your minification approach), and have a test that then beautifies the minification and does another comparison (this makes your testing more robust and more ensured of validity).

These kinds of tests are why you would probably benefit from a BDD-capable framework like Jasmine, as opposed to just pure TDD (ala the results you found of a visual diff being a mess to do), as you are testing behavior and comparisons and prior/post states of functionality/behavior, not just if a is true and still true after being parsed.

Setting up these unit tests could take a while, but its an iterative approach with that large of a codebase...test your initial critical choke points or fragile points fast and early, then extend tests to everything (the way I've always set my teams up is that anything from this point on is not considered complete and RC unless it has Unit Tests...anything old that has no unit tests and has to be updated/touched/maintained must have unit tests written when they are touched, so that you are constantly improving and shrinking the amount of untested code in a more manageable and logic way, while increasing your [code coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)).

Once you have unit tests up and running in a CI, you can then tie them into your build process: fail builds that have no unit tests, or when the unit tests fail send out alerts, proactively monitor on each checkin, etc. etc. Auto-generate documentation with JSDoc3, etc. etc.

The issue you are describing is what CI and unit tests were built for, and more specifically in your case that approach minimizes the impact of the size of the codebase...the size doesn't make it more complex, just makes the duration to get testing working across the board longer.

Then, combine that with JSDoc3 and you are styling better than 90% of most front end shops. It’s incredibly robust and useful to engineers at that point, and it becomes self-perpetuating.

I really could go on and on about this topic, there's a lot of nuance to how you approach it and get a team to rally behind it and make it self-forming and self-perpetuating, and the most important one being writing testable code...but from a concept level...**write unit tests and automate them**. Always.

For too long, frontend developers have been half-assing development, not applying actual engineering rigor and discipline. As frontend has grown more and more powerful and hot, that has to change, and is changing. The concept of well tested, well covered, automated testing and continuous integration for frontend/[RIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_web_application) applications is one of the huge needs of that change.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [Selenium Web Driver](http://seleniumhq.org/) Which allows you to automate tests for web applications in various environments. There are some cloud hosted VM solutions for doing multi environment testing, so you don't get caught out when it works in Webkit but not in IE.

Comment: We actually use that to do some automated tests today. Our application workflows are highly interactive, so it's a lot of work. That covers the basics -- but we're looking for something deeper (and more scientific), ideally.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look into using source maps to help with debugging minimized JavaScript.  source maps will also work with supersets of JavaScript such as CoffeeScript or my new favorite TypeScript.

I use closure compiler which not only minifies, but also will create the source maps.  not to mention it is the most agressive and produces the smallest files.  Lastly you kinda have to know what's going on in minification and write compatible code, your example code could use some refactoring.

check out this article on source maps:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

also check out the documentation for closure compiler, it's got suggestions on how to write better code for minification:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Comment: I might be interesting to switch for source map debugging in some cases, yet how would we do the comparison we are looking for? Do you think that we could readily compare two versions? (The source was just a very simplified example of a block of code that had originally caused this issue.)

Comment: i think that you need as much visibility as possible for your situation, so source maps can only help.  at the end of the day nothing can replace testing and for any large web app. you absolutely need to be using unit tests, automated testing (i use Canoo Webtest / http://webtest.canoo.com/) and manual.

As far as doing a direct comparison between how your old minifier and your new one are doing their jobs i don't think there is any good way to do it.  They do things different by intent, so the output will be different and a one-to-one is kind of moot pint in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not a testing solution, but how about switching to TypeScript to write large JavaScript applications like yours?

I tested it out with TypeScript and its default minification engine and it works fine.

Assuming your `count` argument is an number.

The TypeScript code will be:

```
class ProcessorX {
    ProcessX(count: number): string {
        var value = '';
        value += count.toString();
        value += count.toString();
        count++;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Which produces js like this:

```
var ProcessorX = (function () {
    function ProcessorX() { }
    ProcessorX.prototype.ProcessX = function (count) {
        var value = '';
        value += count.toString();
        value += count.toString();
        count++;
        return value;
    };
    return ProcessorX;
})();
```

Then minified to:

```
var ProcessorX=function(){function n(){}return n.prototype.ProcessX=function(n){var t="";return t+=n.toString(),t+=n.toString(),n++,t},n}()
```

It's on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm9LF/).

If your `count` is a `string`, then this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHFDj/).

Comment: The newer minifier no longer has the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

We use the closure compiler in advanced mode which both minifies and changes code. As such, we compile our unit tests as well, so you could consider minifying your tests alongside your code and running it like that.

Comment: If your tests have generated a fault in them due to the minification then what will test the tests?

Comment: The compiler obviously has tests written against it, the thing we want to avoid is people trying to address functions like someObj['someFunc']() since that will break with advanced optimisation and is an extremely common javascript idiom. The other thing (which is closure specific with the full stack) in our regression tests we want to be sure that css names are referenced through the renaming map.

Comment: What is "closure compiler"? The [Google thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301007/how-to-use-google-closure-compiler)?

Comment: yes. it is a very good js compiler but doesn't work well with the js eco system that arose post 2011. if you use their library and their compiler on advanced mode, the outcomes are pretty amazing