# How to use Google Closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to migrate from the closurebuilder.py script to the [Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) because of this message:

```
../../closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py: Closure Compiler now natively understands and orders Closure dependencies and
```

is prefererred over using this script for performing JavaScript compilation

Since I'm using [Google Closure Library](https://github.com/google/closure-library/) and the [OpenLayers 3](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3), how do I have to call the compiler (compiler.jar) to

- Build an myapp-deps.js dependency file
- Build an minified version myapp.js that includes only used OL3 and CL classes
- Build both with the usage of pre-calculated dependency files of OL3 and CL (e.g. ol3-deps.js)

Let's further say everything is located in the following structure. This almost equals to my own project but it is to big and complex to be posted here directly.

```
project/
    src/
        js/
            <some other js "required" in myapp.js>
            myapp.js
            myapp-deps.js                 # This should be the dependency file
        lib/
            closure/goog/...
            third_party/closure/goog/...  
            myapp.js                      # This should be the minified version
    ol3/
```

I'm thankful for every hint.

Answer (score 2):

Closure Compile can now manage Closure dependencies, that is dependencies defined with `goog.provide` and `goog.require` in the JavaScript code. So you do not need to use the `closurebuilder.py` script anymore. And this is why it's deprecated.

See the wiki page https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies to know about the options/flags Closure Compiler provides for that.

Regarding the generation of `deps` files, which may be necessary for loading js files one by one for debugging/development purposes, you will still need Closure Library's `depswriter.py` script. Closure Compiler has no tool or flag for that. Reading https://github.com/google/closure-library/issues/382 `depswriter.py` is no longer used within Google, but it looks like the script is still maintained.