# Prevent default addition of deps.js

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I am trying to use google closure library for my web app's javascript. I have my JS script in `static` directory along with closure library:

```
static/
  app.js
  closure-library
```

JS code is combined into a single script using closure builder:

```
static/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py \
> --root=./static/closure-library/ \
> --namespace="pr" \
> --output_mode=script \
> --output_file=./static/app-calc.js static/app.js
```

The backend is in Go. Script generated above is included in HTML as:

```
<script src="/static/app-calc.js"></script>
```

However, as soon as the page is loaded, `deps.js` is added to DOM after the above script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="deps.js"></script>
```

Since this file is added without any preceding path, browser this to load this script using current application URL.

Is there any way to change this behavior or prevent addition of `deps.js`?
As far as I can tell, since the entire library has been combined into a single file, there shouldn't be a need for this file. Closure [docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/depswriter) about depswriter mention path being same as `base.js`, but since `base.js` is not even included, I don't see how that's suppose have any to effect on applicaton.

Answer (score 2):

Closurebuilder is deprecated and you should use closure compiler directly instead.  See [How to use Google Closure compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301007/how-to-use-google-closure-compiler) which covers many of your questions.  The wiki page about [Managing Dependencies](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies) has current details.  Note that there is still a lot of old documentation about closure compiler that has not been updated for example https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder.  Some of those pages are still relevant but others are out of date.  The wiki at github is all up to date.

The `deps.js` file is only needed now for debugging when running directly from source code (without compiling). See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Debugging-Uncompiled-Source-Code.

The compiler will be able to take just the pieces of closure-library that you are using and combine it with your code.

Comment: I tried using compiler with the `--dependency_mode` flag. `deps.js` still shows up.

Comment: Can you show the complete compile command you are using?  What do you mean "deps.js still shows up"?  As far as I can tell the only way to generate `deps.js` is with the python scripts like `depswriter.py` or `closurebuilder.py` -- are you still using those?  Also can you show more of directory structure: where source files are, where the compiled output is put?

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable or global object property "CLOSURE_NO_DEPS" to true.  This will prevent base.js from attempting to load the deps.js file.

Details can be found in the code:
https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/base.js#L19